# BadType routing failure in IHP even though types are defined

Tags: haskell, ihp

#### Context

I have a record with a field that is of type `Day` (which corresponds to a field with type `DATE` in my Postgresql database). I have a Create action which works fine (records are saved to the database). However, from the Create action, if I try to redirect to another action and pass in the field with type `Day` like:

```
-- PostsController.hs
action CreatePostAction = do
    let post = newRecord @Post
            post
                |> buildPost
                |> ifValid \case
                    Left post -> do
                        render NewView { .. }
                    Right post -> do
                        let date1 = get #date1 post
                        redirectTo SomeAction { .. }
```

I get this error:

```
Query parameter "date1" needs to be a "UUID" but got "2021-10-16"

Routing failed with: BadType {expectedType = "UUID", value = Just "2021-10-23", field = "date1"}
```

even though `SomeAction`'s  param type is `Day`:

```
-- Types.hs
data PostsController = SomeAction { date1 :: Day }
```

#### Question

Why is the error thrown? And why is the expected type UUID when it should be Day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IHP's AutoRoute only works with the following data types:

- Text
- [Text]
- Maybe Text
- Int
- [Int]
- Maybe Int
- Id

You can find more details in the docs: https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/routing.html#parameter-types

I suggest that you use `SomeAction { date1 :: Text }` as a workaround. You could also use `SomeAction` without any explicit args and then access the date using `param` like this:

```hs
action SomeAction = do
    let date1 :: Day = param "date1"
```